# excel: correct column position

Tags: vba, excel

Actually, it is a simple question, although I don't know if it's possibl to do what I wanted to.

I'm just copying a column from another using this sub:

```
Sub copy_column()
Sheets("FROM").Columns("A").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TO").Columns("A")
End Sub
```

In fact, in my sheet "FROM" my first row with data is the row 3 and then when I copy to "TO" sheet it's starting from row 3 too. My idea was to place it at the row 1 at "TO" sheet.

Is there any way to write something like `Columns("A"-2)` to put it in the right place?

Comment: You will need to copy a smaller part of `Sheets("FROM").Columns("A")` to do what you want. `Range("A3:A1040000")` and paste it to `Sheets("TO").Range("A1")`

Comment: @ScottCraner using this method I get run-time error 1004

Comment: What excel are you using?

Comment: @pnuts using xlUp or something?

Comment: @ScottCraner 2010.

Comment: this errors? : `Sheets("FROM").Range("A3:A1040000").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TO").Range("A1")`

Comment: @ScottCraner I wrote it wrong, but thank you! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative which avoids deleting rows (if you have data you want to keep in other columns for example) is to take an intersection of a range overlaid with itself, but offset...

The following code assumes you have some data in row 1 in the sheet so UsedRange would start from the correct row, but you can change the offset to accommodate missing data in the rows above

```
Dim CopyRange As Range
With Sheets("From")
    Set CopyRange = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("A"))
    Set CopyRange = Application.Intersect(CopyRange, CopyRange.Offset(2, 0))
    CopyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("TO").Cells(1, 1)
End With
```

Comment: I got it. I intentionally thought about using UsedRange but it didn't work at the beginning